# Have to press Enter Twice for a function to work C#

Tags: asp.net, function, enter

I have the following .aspx page.  I'm searching for the words that are in the database, everything works fine.  I  also have a HyperLink which shows a message if the word does not exist in the database.

BUT the only problem is when I search for the word and the word is not in the database it doesn't show the HyperLink from the first time, I have to CLICK ENTER twice for it to work, and CLICK CLEAR twice for it to dissapear.

I know that the problem is that I have the button after the page_load, but I can't find the solution for it.  What I've tried is created another function private void load_data() and copy everything from page_load into it. And in the load_page and button2_click  just call load_data(); It doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
namespace TRI_Portal.ScreenPop.Gloss
{
    public partial class Gloss_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
            {

                HyperLink1.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                HyperLink1.Visible = false;
            }

            String s = Request.QueryString["language"];

            Language1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(s);

        }    

      }
    }
```

I have tried this as well, but no luck.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SetLink();
        }
    }
    private void SetLink()
    {
        if (GridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
        {

            HyperLink1.Visible = true;
        }

        else
        {
            HyperLink1.Visible = false;
        }

        String s = Request.QueryString["language"];

        Language1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(s);
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetLink();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle GridView.DataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SetLink();
}
```

And markup:

```
<asp:GridView OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" ....
```

Remove the code from the Page_Load event.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. But nothing has changed.  Here's my code. I might be doing something wrong. protected void GridView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label();
        } 

 private void label()
        {
            if (GridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
            {

                HyperLink1.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                HyperLink1.Visible = false;
            }

            String s = Request.QueryString["language"];

            Language1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(s);

        }

Comment: That didn't work for me. But I found the solution in emptydatatemplate.